# IE6 background-position with a sprite

Tags: css, sprite, internet-explorer-6, background-position

I have a sprite with two images, top and bottom rounded borders for some feature box. Some example HTML:

```
<div class="box">
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="middle">Content Here</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.box {float:left;width:400px;}
.top,.bottom {float:left;width:400px;height:4px;background-image:url(/images/boxborders.gif);}
.bottom {background-position: 0 -4px;}
.middle {float:left;width:398px;border-left:1px solid #333333;border-right:1px solid #333333;}
```

In FF 3 and 4, Chrome, IE 7, 8 and 9 it displays as it should, with the .top and .bottom divs "hugging" the middle div to create a box effect.

However, in IE6, the .top div shows the whole background image and seems to have increased it's height somehow, even though the developer toolbar is telling me the height is 4px, it clearly isn't as it shows the whole 8px image then roughly the same amount of pixels whitespace below it before the middle div starts.

Has anybody experienced this before? Any feedback appreciated

Thanks

Comment: do you need to add an overflow:hidden property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is add an `overflow: hidden` property.

http://jsfiddle.net/hVvNy/8/

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I don't understand that at all though :\ Why would overflow:hidden change the position of the image?

Comment: @Andy: `overflow:hidden` doesn't change the position of the image, but it does tell IE to not try and keep space for any text inside the `div` (that's why it was about 8px high, instead of 4px). So once the `div` was the right height, the image was in the right position too.